# Why is std::vector iterator invalidation upon reallocation of other vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, implementation, realloc

That's not the exact same copy of other questions on the topic. I've just stumbled into something really strange and can't get how this happened.

```
struct Edge{
    int vertex_a{ 0 };
    int vertex_b{ 0 };
};
typedef std::vector<Edge> EdgeList;

struct Vertex{
    std::vector<int> edge_indices;
};

typedef std::vector<Vertex> VertexList;

    void ContractEdge(int edge_index){
            static int iter = 0;
            ++iter;
            auto& edge = edge_list[edge_index];
            auto& vertex_a = vertex_list[edge.vertex_a - 1];
            auto& vertex_b = vertex_list[edge.vertex_b - 1];
            auto dead_vertex_index = edge.vertex_b;
            std::vector<int> self_edge_array;
            auto& indices = vertex_b.edge_indices;

            for (auto it = indices.begin(); it != indices.end();++it){
                auto current_index = *it;
                auto& edge_of_b = edge_list[current_index];
                if (edge_of_b.vertex_a == dead_vertex_index){
                    edge_of_b.vertex_a = edge.vertex_a;
                }
                if (edge_of_b.vertex_b == dead_vertex_index){
                    edge_of_b.vertex_b = edge.vertex_a;
                }
                if (edge_of_b.vertex_a == edge_of_b.vertex_b){
                    self_edge_array.push_back(current_index);
                }
                else{
//this is the line where reallocation happens
                    vertex_a.edge_indices.push_back(current_index);
                }
            }
            RemoveVertexFromGraph(dead_vertex_index);
            int d = 0;
            for (auto& x : edge_list){
                if ((x.vertex_a > vertex_list.size()) || (x.vertex_b > vertex_list.size()))
                    ++d;
            }
            if (d)
                ++d;

            std::sort(self_edge_array.rbegin(), self_edge_array.rend());
            for (auto self_edge : self_edge_array){
                RemoveEdgeFromGraph(self_edge);
            }
        }
```

In the middle of this function I'm iterating over indices vector of one vertex and occasionly push_back some values to the indices vector of other vertex.

While running this code , I've started to recieve error message "Vector iterator not icrementable".
I've decided to debug closer and found that when I do certain amount of `push_back`s here `vertex_a.edge_indices.push_back(current_index)`, and both the size and the capacity of the vector is 19, the vector implementation calls `_Reserve(1)` method, which calls some reallocate method. 
And after that the indices vector gets reallocated automaticly with all pointers inside of it pointing to the other memory block. That's why the auto it iterator can not be nor compared not incremented, because it becomes invalid pointing to some wrong place.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: are you perhaps asking why `std::vector` doesn't expand its current allocation via `realloc` instead of allocating new memory when it needs to?

Comment: With so much indirection it seems you have managed to push back onto the vector you're traversing. Post a **complete** (but minimal please) example if you don't manage to sort it out. Hint to sort it out: check addresses of vectors, e.g. in a debugger, or via trace output statements.

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the case. The question is obvious, isn't it? It's in the title. So. How could I push_back onto the other vector?)

Comment: your code is so hard to follow... what you are trying to do?

Comment: With graph data structures like these where you're traversing the graph and modifying it simultaneously, I'd kind of go against the standard C++ aesthetic and favor indexed iteration above all -- just for this case, and get used to capturing array (vector in this case) sizes regularly. Otherwise it's very easy to trip up over iterator/pointer invalidation. And yes, `push_back` invalidates iterators.

Comment: A common mistake in these cases, for example, is to traverse a graph that stores nodes contiguously through existing edges and then insert new nodes during traversal. In that case, you're invalidating the entire graph. You want to capture the index range of the graph in those cases prior to traversal, and access everything using indices and sub-indices. Iterators are normally awesome -- but they're gotchas in these kinds of cases where you want to traverse/modify linked structures which are backed/stored by a contiguous, growable data structure.

Comment: Another approach is just use pointers and linked structures repped directly as such. Then you don't have to worry about invalidation anymore. But a lot of performance can get lost that way unless you use a fixed alloc. If you do, then you can get back the spatial locality, and it tends to become a minor overhead that mostly consists of just, say, the size of a 64-bit pointer vs. a 32-bit index.

Comment: You have `int`s named `iter`, secret variables named `edge_list`, `0` and `1` based indexes mixing, references into containers you are modifying that persist over the entire function, global variables, fields of type `int` and variables of type `Vertex` of the same name, and all that before you reach your first "problem"  I would be more surprised if this code didn't have undefined behavior than if it did! After the problem, you have a variable `d` that *does nothing* that you spend a bunch of work calculating. Post *minimal examples* that you have tried to clean up first, not a code dump.

Comment: Ah, I don't think it's exceptionally bad. I think this `iter` variable is some kind of debugging attempt to count the number of iterations. `edge_list` is probably a member of a class and this snippet is incomplete. The 0/1-based index mixing is pretty ridiculous though. Not to say it's good by any means -- just graph-related code using a contiguous backing data structure and indices for adjacency tend to be pretty disgusting in nature unless we wrap away all the grossness (or maybe I'm just used to looking at horrible graph implementations -- not of my own making).

Comment: It could be so much cleaner though if it just used a pointer-based rep, allocating each node/edge/vertex individually, and linking them through pointers. Invalidation issues would go away, the need to leave behind reclaimable tombstones on subsequent insertions would become a non-issue -- the code in general becomes substantially more straightforward. That puts stress on a decent alloc, but correctness first.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your comments. It turned out that at the moment that the problem happens I'm actually pushing_back against the same vector I'm iterating in.
And of course this invalidates iterators. 
So the problem occured to be in a bad data organization and bad coding style. 
I'm looking at your comments now and I understand now that my code is pretty bad. Thanks for indicating that. 
I've also didnt put the whole code for review, because thought it would be enough but sure I could at least show that it is a class and it has some members. 
And reveal more structure. Again sorry for that. 
I think I'd probably need to come up with some other data structure, maybe not doing any dynamic reallocations until the inner algorithm is done. Also the 0 and 1 indexing is lame, I know that. I'm just doing a course task and the task is in txt file and has 1-based indexing.

And yes, d and iter were for breakpoints

Comment: Probably a bit easier is translate those indices when reading/writing the file -- to avoid potential gotchas. Don't let the file format leak into your representation unless it helps somehow. Also I don't think your code was as bad as some people make it out to be -- as said, a graph structure that wants to use an indexed rep for adjacency instead of pointers inevitably has to involve a lot of more explicit indirections (against both container and index). The trick to me is don't mix iterators if you favor that style -- otherwise check out a good sequential/fixed alloc, and use pointers...

Comment: ... and individually-allocated nodes, at least until you get really comfortable navigating around the lowest-level implementations of these structures.